# Android OutputStreamWriter not creating file

Tags: android, file

I am trying to write data from EditText fields to a text file. I have verified that the data is being captured for output in an EditText field that I populate after clicking the Add button. The program runs successfully in the Emulator, but no output file is created. I have added uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" to the Android Manifest xml file. LogCat & Console do not show any errors. I have tried several different methods after reseaching examples here, but no luck. Can anyone point out my issue? Thanks in advance for your help.

```
package john.BRprogram;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
//import android.graphics.Color;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class BRprogramActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {
  private static final String TAG = null;
//
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
 //
    Button addButton;
    Button editButton;
    Button sendButton;
//  
    Spinner array_spinner;
//      
//      activate soft Keyboard
    this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode
      (WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE); 
//
    EditText myCustomer = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    myCustomer.setText("");   
//
    EditText myQuantity = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    myQuantity.setText("");
//      
    EditText myPrice = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    myPrice.setText("");
//    
//      .csv comma separated values file
//        
    try {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.brdata));  
//         
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); 
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        String data = (scanner.next());                  //read data record
        String [] values = data.split(",");           //parse data to fields
//      String [] values = data.split(",(?=([^\"]\"[^\"]\")[^\"]$)");
        if(values.length != 3)     
            Log.v("Example", "Malformed row: " + data); 
            else  
            list.add(values[0] + " " + values[1] + " $" + values[2]);
}
//          
        array_spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);         
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
        (this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); 
        array_spinner.setAdapter(adapter); 
        array_spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener((OnItemSelectedListener) this);
//           
        scanner.close();
//    
}   catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception: "+Log.getStackTraceString(e));
}
//
    addButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addbutton);
    addButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
//    
// get customer number,itemnumber,quantity,price
//
    String writeCustomer = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1)).getText().toString().trim();
//  itemNumber from list selection
    String writeQuantity = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2)).getText().toString().trim();
    String writePrice = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3)).getText().toString().trim();
//
    String newRecord = writeCustomer + "," + writeQuantity + "," + writePrice; 

    EditText myString = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    myString.setText(newRecord);        
//          
// write seq to output file             
//              
    try {
        OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("broutput.txt",0));
        out.write(newRecord);   
        out.close(); 
    }catch (Exception e){
      Log.v("test", "record written");
}                       

//
            EditText myQuantity = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
            myQuantity.setText("");
//      
            EditText myPrice = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
            myPrice.setText("");
            Log.v("test", "ADD button clicked");
}
});
//
    editButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.editbutton);
    editButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            Log.v("test", "EDIT button clicked");
}
});    
//
    sendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendbutton);
    sendButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
//
            EditText myCustomer = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            myCustomer.setText("");
//
            EditText myQuantity = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
            myQuantity.setText("");
//      
            EditText myPrice = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
            myPrice.setText("");
            Log.v("test", "SEND button clicked");
}
});

}
//  ***  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pfasw0bbe_4  ***
//
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
//  
    String selection = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    String [] priceField = selection.split("\\$");       //parse price field
    String [] item = selection.split("_");         //parse item number 
    String itemNumber = item[0];   
//
    EditText myQuantity = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    myQuantity.setText("");
//      
    EditText myPrice = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    myPrice.setText(priceField[1]);
}
//
   public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
//nothing here      
}
}
```

Comment: I don't think you need the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission since you're only writing to a file private to your application. If that's the case, you won't normally be able to navigate to the file in a file manager, since it's private to your application. Are you 100% sure it's not been created? What `Exception` is being thrown, if any? By the way, it's best practice to use constant names, rather than their integer values, so when you open the file, use `openFileOutput("broutput.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to create and/or specify the directory where you wish to save the file. I didn't see that anywhere in your code. It might look something like this:

```
if (Environment.getExternalStorageState() == null) {
            directory = new File(Environment.getDataDirectory()
                    + "/RobotiumTestLog/");
            photoDirectory = new File(Environment.getDataDirectory()
                    + "/Robotium-Screenshots/");
            /*
             * this checks to see if there are any previous test photo files
             * if there are any photos, they are deleted for the sake of
             * memory
             */
            if (photoDirectory.exists()) {
                File[] dirFiles = photoDirectory.listFiles();
                if (dirFiles.length != 0) {
                    for (int ii = 0; ii <= dirFiles.length; ii++) {
                        dirFiles[ii].delete();
                    }
                }
            }
            // if no directory exists, create new directory
            if (!directory.exists()) {
                directory.mkdir();
            }

            // if phone DOES have sd card
        } else if (Environment.getExternalStorageState() != null) {
            // search for directory on SD card
            directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + "/RobotiumTestLog/");
            photoDirectory = new File(
                    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                            + "/Robotium-Screenshots/");
            if (photoDirectory.exists()) {
                File[] dirFiles = photoDirectory.listFiles();
                if (dirFiles.length > 0) {
                    for (int ii = 0; ii < dirFiles.length; ii++) {
                        dirFiles[ii].delete();
                    }
                    dirFiles = null;
                }
            }
            // if no directory exists, create new directory to store test
            // results
            if (!directory.exists()) {
                directory.mkdir();
            }
        }
```

When you save data from your app, you have to remember that it is running on the Android, and not your computer, so all data is going to be written to your Android, not your comp. You have to pull the data after it is written to view it. Make sure you that you created a local directory on your device and make sure you check for an SD card. The code I listed will show you how to do everything you need.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I specified the full directory path in: OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("/Documents and Settings/Owner/workspace/BRprogram/res/raw/broutput.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));  File was not output but I did get a new 'catch Exception - record not written' in Logcat. Is there a better way to see exactly what the Exception was?

Comment: You can't write to the raw file. That is why you are having your issue. You need to save it to the local device, and not to a development file. You aren't saving to the computer, you are saving to the device. Use some of the code I've listed above and you should be fine. Give it a try and see what happens.

Comment: I'm running this on the Emulator only and haven't reached the point to put it on the Android phone. By 'local device' do you mean the Emulator? I began suspecting this and found some adb commands to 'push/pull' from the AVD device. Many thanks for the suggestions btw. I'll give your code a try.

Comment: Yes, or whatever device you are running it on. I don't know if you can write data to an emulator, you may be able to, but I haven't tried it. This is why I always develop with a real device. The code above will work, if you have any other questions about it, let me know. I'm happy to help. If it works feel free to upvote and/or accept the answer :)

Comment: Blaine, I imported android.os.Environment and java.io.file. The compiler keeps barking at me about 'directory' and 'photodirectory'. How do you have them defined in your program please?

Comment: Those are just class variables that I created. Feel free to create your own.

Comment: Making some progress. I have the app running on the phone but not creating output file. Discovered that the phone is not rooted even though I though I had successfully rooted it before. Just want to thank everyone for you excellent responses. Closing this thread as complete due to time.

Answer (score 0):

I've actually experienced a problem like this; everything seemed fine, but my code wasn't working.  My problem was the characters in the file name I was writing.  For example, I tried writing the file name `my_file - date 07/11/2012`.  This caused problems because it treated each `/` as a cue to begin a new directory!  For this reason, I discovered I could not have any `/` (or `:`, for some reason) in my file names.  Would this be your problem?

If this is your problem, then you could do what I did: perform a `newRecord.replace('/', '-');` to replace all `/` in your file name with a `-` (if you are fine with having `-`'s instead).

On a side note, why are you logging "record written" in your the catch of your try/catch statement?  If it catches a problem, doesn't that mean it wasn't written?

Comment: Changed the openFileOutput as suggested and removed Manifest xml entry. No Exceptions noted and file was not created. Also modified the output data string as suggested. Original output was 12345,999,.55 New data is 12345999.55 Thought that the commas might be special characters. Same results, no file created. Ran a dos prompt command DIR/s broutput.txt to verify that file was not on system. No error entries in LogCat or Console.